# Determining the path requiring the minimum number of "jumps" to get from point A to point B on a continuous plane, given arbitrary circular obstacles?

Tags: geometry, optimization

I've come across a curious problem that has stumped me for the last week.

The problem is thus: say that you are trying to get from Point A to Point B on a plane, but can only move by "jumping" in a straight line by some specific number of units ("jumps" of length less than the maximum are permitted). There are some number of circular obstacles in the plane at some given locations. Given just a list of these obstacles (their positions and radii), the positions of the two end points (A and B), and the maximum jump length, how can I determine the optimal path (or something close to it, at least?) to take? (By "optimal", I mean the path using the fewest number of jumps; and then, within the space of paths using that number of jumps, the path crossing the least distance.)

I've put together a few rudimentary illustrations to demonstrate the problem and highlight some aspects that have caught my attention. In the images linked below, lines represent jumps and dots represent vertices; the blue path is the path I believe to be the optimal one, while examples of inferior alternatives are shown in gray:

- [Example demonstrating the triviality of the no-obstacle scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggumL.png)
- [Example demonstrating navigating around a simple obstacle and minimizing distance in so doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZUcd.png)
- [Example demonstrating the preference of minimizing jumps over minimizing distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O90pY.png)
- [Example demonstrating a case where less-than-maximum-length jumps are preferred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkC5k.png)

I'm certain that any full solution will be necessarily multi-part, since it will need to optimize two different metrics in order (first the number of jumps, then total distance - but the latter never at the cost of the former). I've been able to figure out (or at least determine how I would go about figuring out) explicit algorithms for certain special cases (such as the one-obstacle-on-$\overline{\rm AB}$ case depicted in examples 2 and 3), but I am increasingly having my doubts that there is an accessible general solution that does not involve approximation.

It's at this point that I've become stuck, so I'd love to hear other peoples' thoughts on this problem! I don't need a mathematically perfect solution, if one could even exist - this problem originally came up from a matter of practical implementation, so an approximative one is entirely satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Dijkstra’s Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/), with initial node being A. First ,consider number of jumps to each node as a "distance" and thus you get pathes with least number of jumps to node B. Then, geting shortest distance for each path is easy. For the points were the distance between them is larger than the allowed length of jump ,consider the points to be a disconnected.

Comment: This is definitely where my head was at as well! However, I'm hesitant to use Dijkstra because I'm not sure how to cleanly apply it to a continuous plane (I.E. a situation without discrete nodes). Do you mean to recommend that I approximate the plane as a large number of nodes, each of which connects to every accessible neighbor? Because I had that thought, but became concerned once I realized how computation-intensive that approximation would be. I'm curious for your thoughts on this. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: yeah, but I will consider using a "smart approximation" like for places away from obstacle you will have less nodes with big jumps. For places next to obstacles I will consider the points of tagency in most of the cases.